Avoid rebuilding Next.js for deployments because of env vars needed in API routes
I have a next.js application which uses the Firebase-Admin SDK within its API routes. The Admin SDK requires a set of secrets, which are read from environment variables at runtime.
When the next build command is run, these variables are expected to be available, or the process fails.
From what I understand on a page you would use getServerSideProps or Server Side Components to tell next.js not to evaluate this code. But these features are not relevant for API routes.
What actually happens in the build process, in terms of how the code is evaluated / invoked which means that the SDK is actually trying to read the variables?

What error are you receiving? Normally, if the environment file is correctly configured, there should be no issue accessing the secret keys during the build or dev start process on Next.js.
Next.js supports loading environment variables from a .env file. The environment variables are loaded at build time and can be used in both client and server-side code.
.env file example:
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://api.example.com
SECRET_KEY=mysecretkey



// pages/index.js
const HomePage = () => {
  console.log('Public API URL:', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL);
  console.log('Secret Key:', process.env.SECRET_KEY); // Server-side only
  return <div>Welcome to Next.js!</div>;
};

export default HomePage;



Note: Public variables (prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC_) can be accessed on both client and server sides. Private variables (without the prefix) are only accessible on the server side. Always add .env to .gitignore to keep your secrets secure.

So, do you have an .env file and is it located in the root directory?
Even if you have an .env file, are you unable to access the SDK secret keys during the local build process?
Is the structure of your .env file correct? Or have you set these secret keys as environment variables in a deployment environment like Vercel?

Also, this site might help you:
https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-nextjs#0
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

so I can make the variables available, but I don't want to put these secrets into my deployment pipeline if I don't have to. And if adding them to the pipeline is the only way to get things to work, I'd like to know what is happening in the build step to require them to be available.
It doesn't seem quite right to have them in the pipeline as this breaks the 12 factor application principles, that the variable should be injected at runtime. The same build artefact should be able to be deployed to different environments

Next.js requires server-side environment variables to be available during the build process. If your project is not shared publicly or in an environment like Docker, you can store the environment variables in the .env file without making them NEXT_PUBLIC and build the project. As long as you do not commit the .env file to GitHub, there should be no issues. Similarly, you can integrate these keys securely in the deployment environment by following the platform's documentation.
Next.js uses server-side environment variables without sending them to the client, performing secure operations on the server side. To pass the results to the client, you need to use API routes or Server-Side Props. If you need to perform a public build, you can use CI/CD tools like GitHub Actions or Jenkins to provide the necessary keys for the Next.js build externally.
In summary, environment variables intended for client-side use need to be prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC to be available on the client side. Otherwise, they will be used only on the server side. To securely connect to the Admin SDK API endpoint from the client, use API routes or Server-Side Props. Enhance security between the client and server with JWT tokens, iron-session, or middleware, and restrict server-side access to the Supabase Admin environment through the created API. For public builds, add environment variables using GitHub Actions or Docker. Finally, using next.config.js allows for more organized management of keys, specifying whether they are for build or runtime, but essentially runtime keys mean NEXT_PUBLIC keys.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/env
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes

